# Reference request: J-P Serre, "Groupes finis d'automorphismes d'anneaux locaux réguliers"

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Does anyone have, or know a link to, a copy of the paper named in the title? It is published in Colloq. d'Alg. École Norm. de Jeunes Filles, Paris (1967), 1-11. I do not have ready access to Serre's Collected Works.

Comment: this is the [WorldCat entry](https://www.worldcat.org/title/colloque-dalgebre-6-7-mai-paris/oclc/11896611&referer=brief_results) --- listing the libraries that hold this volume (it does not appear to be in the collected works)

Comment: Google has [scanned it](https://books.google.fr/books?hl=fr&id=RefuAAAAMAAJ&dq=intitle%3AColloque+d%27algèbre%2C+6-7+mai+1967%2C+Paris+%2F&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=anneaux) but has not made it available because of copyright restrictions, so going to a library seems the only option.

Comment: I have a scanned copy, send me an email and I'll send it to you.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker: I had not known about WorldCat. Thank you.

Comment: @Matthieu Romagny: thank you for the scan.